# Indefinite integral of $e^{\frac{n} {x^{1 +a}}}\cdot x^m$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int\exp\left(n \over x^{1 + a}\right)\, x^{m}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
This integral is aim at calculating an expression like the expression between stress and strain, but there is little effects on using integration by parts, so I have no idea which way to choose.

If impossible, can you use Taylor's formula to calculate an approximate expression way ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: For a start, you could let us know what $n$, $m$, $\alpha$ are (or at least the range of values they may take) and what the domain of integration is. Next, you could let us know what kind of result you are interest in: Asymptotics for one of the parameters to infinity? Just a bound saying your integral is finite? An exact result? Finally, you could show us what you already tried

Comment: the result by Mathematica is $$-\frac{(\alpha +1) x^{m+1} \left(-x^{\frac{n}{\alpha +1}}\right)^{-\frac{(\alpha +1)
   (m+1)}{n}} \Gamma \left(\frac{(m+1) (\alpha +1)}{n},-x^{\frac{n}{\alpha +1}}\right)}{n}$$

Comment: But how is this integral evaluated?

Comment: MathJax hints:  for multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so x^{12} gives $x^{12}$ in contrast to x^12 which gives $x^12$.  If you put a backslash before alpha, you get $\alpha$.  To get a center dot for multiplication, use \cdot, so 1 \cdot 2 gives $1 \cdot 2$

Comment: I have used Taylor's formula to substitude e^{n/x^{α+1}}, but Taylor's formula only works well around the extend-point, which is not suitable to express the function relation between y and variable x. so i failed to get proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. a, m, n aren't int(they are constant ) , and they have no times relation each other. If you use Γ (x,y),  x,y must be int.so it may cannot use Γ (x,y). Last, the integration above is just a part of calculation.I want a final experssion about x, for i have to use this expression about x at latter calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int x^m \exp \left(x^{\frac{n}{\alpha+1}}\right)\,\mathrm d x$$

Substitute $u=x^{m+1}$ to get

$$I=\frac{1}{m+1}\int\exp\left({u^{\frac{n}{(\alpha+1)(m+1)}}}\right)\,\mathrm d u$$

This integral is expressible in terms of [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) using the identity
$$\int \exp{x^a}\,\mathrm d x=-\frac{\mathop\Gamma \left( \frac 1a, -x^a\right)}{a(-1)^{\frac 1a}}+C$$

We thus get
\begin{align*}I&=\frac{1}{m+1}\cdot\left(-\frac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)\mathop{\Gamma}\left(\frac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)}{n},-u^\frac{n}{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)}\right)}{n\left(-1\right)^\frac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)}{n}}\right)\\
&= -\dfrac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)}{n},-x^\frac{n}{\alpha+1}\right)}{n\left(-1\right)^\frac{\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(m+1\right)}{n}}+C
\end{align*}

which is equivalent to Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer in comments.

Comment: I changed the pattern of integral.The constant "n"  became numerator of x^(1+a), and "m""n""α" are not int, can i also use Γ()?  Could you please answer the question again?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you can still use the incomplete gamma, substitute $u=n^{\frac{m+1}{-(a+1)}}x^{m+1}$ and you will be able to use the $\int \exp x ^ a\,\mathrm d x$ identity again.